# Extract names from file in python

Tags: python, regex, list

I'm dealing with a file where I want to extract the names and append them to a list. The names are formatted like this:

"Firstname LastnameAnotherfirstname Anotherlastname" etc...

I'm not an experienced programmer, therefore, I haven't got a lot of regex lingo in the back of my head so a little help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [This](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) may be relevant

Comment: So you want to split the names based on the capital letters?

Comment: I doubt this is the actual format. If it is - make sure it is absolutely impossible to change the format before proceeding any further.

Answer (score 0):

Find name by Upper Case

```
import re

file_open = open('file_name.txt').read()
value = re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', file_open)
print(value)
```

You get a list of name.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import re
regex = r"[A-Z][a-z]*\ [A-Z][a-z]*"
test_str = "Firstname LastnameAnotherfirstname Anotherlastname"
output = re.findall(regex, test_str)
print output
```